# How to set the start time and end time in calculating moving averages?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, moving-average

I am trying to calculate moving averages of 15 minutes, 8 hours and 24 hours from 10 second recorded data. How should I set the start time and end time to calculate the moving averages?

I have used the following code for calculating the moving average

```
 Gas_432.set_index('RecTime').rolling(90).mean()
 Gas_432.between_time('2019-05-31 00:00:00','2019-07-04 08:08:21')
```

But I am getting an error message 
    `TypeError: Index must be DatetimeIndex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.truncate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.truncate.html) after creating `DatetimeIndex`:

```
#if not datetimes
Gas_432['RecTime'] = pd.to_datetime(Gas_432['RecTime'])

Gas_432 = (Gas_432.set_index('RecTime')
                  .truncate('2019-05-31 00:00:00','2019-07-04 08:08:21')
                  .rolling(90)
                  .mean())
```

Comment: I get an error    `ValueError: Cannot convert arg ['2019-05-31 00:00:00'] to a time`

Comment: @D.Banerjee - how working `Gas_432['RecTime'] = pd.to_datetime(Gas_432['RecTime'], errors='coerce')` ?

Comment: The first line of code is running fine. I get the error for the second line of code

Comment: @D.Banerjee - it seems your pandas version is old, so try convert to datetimes both strings `.between_time(pd.to_datetime('2019-05-31 00:00:00'),pd.to_datetime('2019-07-04 08:08:21'))`

Comment: Got the error `ValueError: Cannot convert arg [Timestamp('2019-05-31 00:00:00')] to a time`

Comment: @D.Banerjee - You are roght, need [`DataFrame.truncate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.truncate.html), sorry.

Comment: Can you please tell how to do it?

Comment: answer was chenged